# React Material-UI slider value keeps resetting to zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building an interface where you choose a radio and it will reveal different form elements.

When a slider is revealed the value change gets set into an object that is rendered on the page.

In this example I have it so it does update the object but the slider no longer moves even though the value is getting correctly set if you click on the line.

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-dawn-e5zyu

The object I am setting is declared in the parent :

```
  const defaultActivity = {
    group: "",
    a: 0,
    b: 0
  };

  const [activity, setActivity] = useState(defaultActivity);
```

Then in the child component that contains the slider the `handleChange` function is use within that component and I also use a parent function to access `setActivity`.

```
const TestSlider = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);

// This sets the slider value to the activity object
// if you comment this line out then the sliders slide correctly

props.onDataChanged(props.name.toLowerCase(), newValue);

  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
        {props.name}
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={value}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        step={props.step}
        marks
        min={0}
        max={props.max}
        name={props.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And that `onDataChanged` method in the parent

```
  const onDataChanged = (name, value) => {
    setActivity({
      ...activity,
      [name]: value
    });
  };
```

As I noted in the comment there, if you remove the `onDataChanged` method then the sliders work again.  I have tried moving `handleChange` to the parent as well but that did not help.

After creating this Sandbox I seem to have a new problem that is sporadic and unclear to me steps to replicate where I am getting the error :
`Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`

Maybe related to broken slider issue or something else I screwed up.  Thanks in advance for any help with this, I am trying hard to learn my way around React but this problem has me really stumped.

**============= UPDATE: Closer to expected and a new problem =============**

Still playing with this and decided to try and use `onChangeCommitted` on the slider to try and disconnect the value getting set in the slider with it getting set to the main object.  Now it slides and updates the value which sticks in the object but gets reset to 0 for the slider UI.  Hard to explain so maybe easier if you go play with it and see what I mean.  I think the way I am setting the default state is probably the issue but not sure how to refactor this :

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-euler-0dv69?file=/src/TestSlider.js:116-163

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of the problem is that the component `RenderSwitch` is created (declared) inside the `AddActivitySelect` (`SelectForm`) component. Moving `RenderSwitch` outside and passing all necessary props fixes the problem. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-https-hdfth?file=/src/SelectFom.js:1150-1167).

What happened:

- When you call `props.setActivity` in `TestSlider`, the `activity` state updates in `App`
- `App` re-renders which causes `SelectForm` to re-render also.
- Because a completely new `RenderSwitch` component is created inside `SelectForm`, the previous one in unmounted (destroyed).
- The new `RenderSwitch` is rendered, calls `React.useState(0)`, and that's why the slider `value` is 0